# How can I install php on Windows

Tags: php, windows, command-line-interface

I want to install PHP on Windows 10 Pro, I've tried both downloading PHP 7.1 and 7.0.14 from the official website, but for some reason I can't find php.exe in the folder I download (there seems to be no executable at all).

Where can I find the binary? My goal is to be able to run PHP from the Command Prompt.

Comment: why are you not trying xampp or wamp?

Comment: @DeepKakkar I only found 32 bits version for windows.

Comment: Give that one a try @TommasoTheaCioni . Should be no problem

Comment: @Mitch Ok I'm downloading it right now thanks.

Comment: instead of installing part by part why don't you use total solution like xampp/ampps/wamp??

Comment: @reza I'm downloading xampp right now like I said in the earlier comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you get your version of PHP from? http://windows.php.net/download/ I've just downloaded the ZIP from there and it contained php-win.exe

Check you've not accidentally downloaded the php source

Comment: I can't believe this... I downloaded the freaking source... Thanks, I feel super stupid right now. I'm upvoting your answer in 8 minutes

Comment: Haha no worries, it's the simplest things that trip us up.

Answer (score 1):

## Tutorial

#### recommendation: install powershell latest version

#### Install scoop - https://scoop.sh/

1- on powershell: `iwr -useb get.scoop.sh | iex`

#### Install php (latest version)

- scoop install php

#### Install php (specific version)

1. scoop bucket add php
2. scoop search php
3. scoop install php/php7.4.26

#### Install composer

- scoop install composer

#### Composer/php folder:

- C:\Users\username\scoop\apps\php7.4
- C:\Users\username\scoop\apps\composer

#### where to config composer/php manually

- C:\Users\username\scoop\persist

#### enable php extensions

1. on terminal `cd C:\Users\username\scoop\persist`
2. on terminal(will open vscode) `code .`
3. edit C:\Users\username\scoop\persist\php7.4\conf.d\extensions.ini

#### extensions.ini - example

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
extension=fileinfo
extension=curl
extension=pdo_sqlite
extension=pdo_mysql
extension_dir=C:\Users\username\scoop\apps\php7.4\7.4.26\ext
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you're not asking about live deployment and are just wanting to learn some PHP by messing around with it.

The easiest way to do it is with a package like [Xampp](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) or [Wamp](http://www.wampserver.com/en/)

These will both install a basic stack for you which is fine for development.

If you're running the build of Windows 10 that has bash for Windows installed you can use apt-get.  That's pretty easy and also fine for messing around with.

Or you could just use Docker which is more complicated than these ways but is really worth learning how to do.

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Install [WAMPP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/)  or [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html) and start development in php.

Answer (score 0):

You can install xampp or wamp server for windows.
The major Difference Between WAMP, LAMP, MAMP AND XAMPP is operating system.

- Lamp is for Linux operating system.
- Wamp is for windows operating system.
- Mamp is for Mac OS X operating system.
- xampp is for x-os, apache, mysql, php , perl.